# Given a string s, find the substring with k elements that contains the maximum number of vowels among the list ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

Tags: python, arrays, string, combinations, python-itertools

Given a string s, I want to find the substring of length k which contains the maximum number of vowels among the list ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
The user gets to input the string s and its length k.
For exemple if s = "sfjfio" and k = 3 then the output should be the string "fio"
If I have multiple substrings satisfying this condition then the output should be the substring which starts at the lowest index.
If no substring satisfies the requirements then I want the output to be just the original string s back. I started with this code but I got kinda confused and stuck. It seems to work but doesn't always give the right answer when I try several examples.
I just started with python a few days ago and not super knowledgeable yet. Any help would be really great !

```
s = input("please enter s ")
k = input("please enter k ")

from itertools import combinations

allsubstrings = [s[a:b] for a, b in combinations(range(len(s) + 1), r = 2)]
#if I am right this should give me all the possible substrings in s

#I will only take the ones of length k and put them in an array
substring = []
for i in allsubstrings:
    if len(i) == k:
        substring.append(i)

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
vowcount = []
#here I create an empty array to store the number of vowels in each substring

#now I will loop over each substring and check if it contains a vowel 
#I need to check if it contains each one of my vowels though I am not really sure if my code does that or just checks for one of the vowels
for j in substring:
    count = 0
    for i in vowels:
        if i in j:
            count = count + 1
        vowcount.append(count)

#now I check the maximum number of vowels in a given substring
#since I am looping through the substrings in order their vowel count also gets stored in order in my vowcount array thus I can take the index of the max(vowcount) as the index of the substring j that satisfies the condition
if vowcount:
    if max(vowcount) != 0:
        print(substring[vowcount.index(int(max(vowcount)))])
else:
   print(s)
```

Comment: Please give an example of an input that gives the wrong result, the result you get, and the result you expect instead.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand why you are creating all the substrings and then filtering them down to the ones of the appropriate length. Hint: can you think of a mathematical rule, given that your substring is `s[a:b]` and the desired length is `k`, that relates `a` to `b`?

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hi Karl, this is an example that fails: s = ioosdfghjkaeibnffbjfbnfoii with k = 4, the output should be "ioos" but the program returns the full string s back

Comment: Actually for the s[a:b] part I don't exactly understand what a or b stand for ? (I just copied it from documentation) does the range [a:b] give me the length as in the length of that interval is the length of my substrings ? if so I could do [0:k-1] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need itertools for this, you can just iterate over all the possible substrings, which start from positions `0` to `len(s)-k` and are `k` characters long. You also don't need to store the vowel count for each substring, just save the substring whenever the vowel count is higher than the previous maximum. You should combine your code into a function to make it easier to call for different combinations of inputs. For example:

```
def max_vowels(s, k):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    # initialise our state variables
    vmax = -1     # maximum number of vowels seen in a subatring
    smax = ''     # the substring in which we found the maximum
    # iterate over all the possible substrings, which start from positions 0 to len(s)-k
    for i in range(len(s)-k+1):
        # extract the substring
        substr = s[i:i+k]
        # count the number of vowels
        num_vowels = sum(1 if c in vowels else 0 for c in substr)
        # is it a new maximum count? if so, update our state
        if (num_vowels > vmax):
            vmax = num_vowels
            smax = substr
    # all substrings visited, return the one with the most vowels
    return smax
        
print(max_vowels('sfjfio', 3))
print(max_vowels('ioosdfghjkaeibnffbjfbnfoii', 4))
```

Output:

```
fio
ioos
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach that utilizes [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), if you are not allowed to use library methods just add your own logic for counting the number of vowels in one string to `num_vowels_in_str` below:

```
from collections import Counter

def num_vowels_in_str(s):
    ch_counts = Counter(s.lower())
    return sum(ch_counts[ch] for ch in "aeiou")

s = input("Please enter s: ")
k = int(input("Please enter k: "))

k_length_substrs = [
    s[i:j]
    for i in range(len(s))
    for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)
    if j - i == k
]

num_vowels_per_substr = [
    num_vowels_in_str(substring)
    for substring in k_length_substrs
]

max_vowels = max(num_vowels_per_substr)

result_index = next(
    i 
    for i, num_vowels in enumerate(num_vowels_per_substr)
    if num_vowels == max_vowels
)

result = k_length_substrs[result_index]
print(result)
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter s: sfjfio
Please enter k: 3
fio
```